# MS SQL Stored Procedure is not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table named Attendance and I Insert data into this table by using stored procedure data for first_term, it inserts successfully but when we insert data for second_term it is not inserted properly.

My database table:

```
        /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Attendance]    Script Date:   11/01/201******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendance](
  [attendanceid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [admission_no] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [totalattendance_firstterm] [int] NULL,
  [totalworkingdays_firstterm] [int] NULL,
  [totalattendance_secondterm] [int] NULL,
  [totalworkingday_secondterm] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And my stored procedure as follows:

```
  ALTER proc [dbo].[student_attendancedetails]
  (
  @admission_no nvarchar(50) ,
  @totalattendance_firstterm int,
  @totalworkingdays_firstterm int,
  @totalattendance_secondterm int,
  @totalworkingday_secondterm int
  )
 as 
 BEGIN
 IF NOT EXISTS(select admission_no from Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO       Attendance(admission_no,totalattendance_firstterm,totalworkingdays_firstterm,   totalattendance_secondterm,totalworkingday_secondterm)values(@admission_no,@t   otalattendance_firstterm,@totalworkingdays_firstterm,@totalattendance_seconderm,@totalworkingday_secondterm)
END
ELSE IF(
(select totalattendance_firstterm from Attendance where   admission_no=@admission_no)is null or (select totalattendance_firstterm from   Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)=0)
BEGIN
UPDATE Attendance set   totalattendance_firstterm=@totalattendance_firstterm where   admission_no=@admission_no
 END

ELSE IF(
  (select totalworkingdays_firstterm from Attendance where   admission_no=@admission_no)is null or (select totalworkingdays_firstterm  from Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)=0)
  BEGIN
  UPDATE Attendance set    totalworkingdays_firstterm=@totalworkingdays_firstterm where      admission_no=@admission_no
  END

  ELSE IF(
   (select totalattendance_secondterm from Attendance where     admission_no=@admission_no)is null or (select totalattendance_secondterm    from Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)=0)
  BEGIN
 UPDATE Attendance set   totalattendance_secondterm=@totalattendance_secondterm where     admission_no=@admission_no
  END
   ELSE IF(
   (select totalworkingday_secondterm from Attendance where    admission_no=@admission_no)is null or (select totalworkingday_secondterm from Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)=0)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Attendance set    totalworkingday_secondterm=@totalworkingday_secondterm where    admission_no=@admission_no
    END

  END

  GO
```

When we execute my stored procedure as follows:

```
 exec student_attendancedetails '2089',89,120,0,0
 exec student_attendancedetails '2089',0,0,98,150
```

It will give the following result:

[image]

But I want my result as given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very very simple. When you run:

```
IF condition1
  code1
ELSE IF condition2
  code2
ELSE IF condition2
  code3
ELSE IF condition3
  code4
...
```

Only one (`code1/code2/code3/code4`) will be executed. Based on your code I assume you want to update twice. So you need something like:

```
IF condition1
BEGIN
  INSERT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  IF condition2
    UPDATE1
  IF condition3
    UPDATE2
  IF condition4
   UPDATE3
END
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384194)**</kbd>

*Warning:*

```
(select totalattendance_secondterm from Attendance where admission_no=@admission_no)=0
```

will fail when your query return more than one row. But you probably have unique/primary key on `admission_no`. If no I suggest adding it.